# htaccess 301 redirection of urls w/ parameters to url w/o parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to do a simple 301 direct on some old URLs that have parameters to them.

e.g.

```
/dir/page1/?id=4590
/dir/page1/?id=45
/dir2/page5/?id=4590
/dir2/page9/?id=45
/page90/?id=45etc
...
```

I want a 301 redirect of the above urls to the corresponding urls w/o parameters:

```
/dir/page1
/dir2/page5
/dir2/page9
/page90
```

My experience with .htaccess is limited. What would be the simplest and the most correct way to enable the above redirects to actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```